What are some examples of asymmetrically mutual intelligibility?
Probably most of the time, dialect >>>>> standard language than standard language > dialect.
I read about Portuguese understand Spanish more than vice versa.
Here is an answer of Russian VS Ukrainian:
Russian VS Ukrainian
Danish VS Norwegian VS Swedish
Probably Moroccan Arabic >>> Egyptian Arabic than vice versa:
Egyptian Arabic
Personal experience:
Japanese understand more written Chinese than vice versa as Chinese do not read kanas which convey grammatical information but Japanese can guess the meaning of Hanzi.
Apart from these, what other examples?

It is not obvious whether “A>B” means “A understands B better than B understands A” or the reverse.

@AntonSherwood A>B = A understands B better

Danes understand Swedish more easily than Swedes understand Danish.
Dutch-speakers understand Afrikaans more easily than Afrikaans-speakers understand Dutch.
Poles understand Russian more easily than Russians understand Polish.
As you say, Portuguese-speakers understand Spanish more easily than Spanish-speakers understand Portuguese.
Spanish-speakers understand Italian more easily than Italians understand Spanish.
Scots-speakers understand English much more easily than English-speakers understand Scots (note that whilst linguists may argue Scots rises to the level of a distinct language, most Scots and English speakers would consider it a dialect of English).
Slovenes understand BCMS more easily than BCMS-speakers understand Slovenian.
Estonians understand Finnish more easily than Finns understand Estonian.
Azeris understand Turkish more easily than Turkish-speakers understand Azerbaijani.
In most cases it's best explained as a result of asymmetric exposure. The more easily-understood languages is typically the one that is (regionally) more dominant, and so speakers of the less easily-understood language typically have greater exposure to it than vice versa, and so have acquired more passive competence in it.
In some cases, asymmetric intelligibility is also explained in terms of one language being more conservative phonologically or morphologically (e.g. Dutch is more conservative morphologically than Afrikaans, etc), but it seems to me that this is at best a marginal factor, as most of these examples also show the effects of asymmetric exposure (e.g. more media is produced in Dutch than Afrikaans, so Afrikaans-speakers are exposed to more Dutch than vice versa), and in some cases (such as Slovene & BCMS) the more conservative variety is actually the less intelligible one, as the effects of exposure seem to dominate.

I’m not sure it’s true that Danes are exposed to more Swedish media than vice versa. There may be more Swedish media produced, but most of it is not aired on Danish tv. The amount of Swedish media on Danish tv and Danish media on Swedish tv seems roughly equal to me. Those who live in the borderlands of course get each other’s channels as well, but that’s only a small part of each country (though containing two of the three largest cities). The same is true for Norwegian, and Norwegians are the best of all the Scandinavians at understanding their neighbours.

@JanusBahsJacquet Bokmål effectively gives Norwegians exposure to what is, moreorless, written Danish, and it's far more commonly used than Nynorsk. I'll remove the example with Danish & Swedish at the end though

True about written Bokmål, but that doesn’t necessarily give much of an advantage with the vagaries of spoken Danish. The more commonly advanced theory is that the greatest advantage the Norwegians have is their emphasis on dialects and giving even smaller, more obscure dialects airtime through tv anchors and such things. In Sweden, you might get a Scanian presenter here and there, but mostly it’s Central Swedish – and in Denmark, you pretty much never hear any dialects on tv, only ‘Standard Danish’ (which is roughly Copenhagen-based).

Levantine >> Morrocan
This as well as your Egyptian example is due to Levantine and Egyptian exposure across the Middle East (amongst other things)
Levantine, Egyptian, Maghrebi, MSA ... are distinct from each other and aren't mutually intelligible but certain factors (such as media exposure) help in bridging the gaps.
In comparison, Portuguese and Spanish are much more closely related when compared to the above.
Although both can understand each other (to a certain extent) but Spanish speakers tend to find Portuguese more difficult to understand! (Media exposure might play a role. Spanish being noted as somewhat simpler might to (subjective) )
Afrikaans >> Dutch (as above, Afrikaans --> simpler grammar)
